# Can anyone work out the CSS that is causing my hover link to be the wrong color?

Tags: css, colors

I have just spent an hour going through my CSS file trying to establish why one of my links has the wrong shade of green when you hover over it.

The website is [www.playlistforlife.org.uk](http://www.playlistforlife.org.uk)

and the link in question is about halfway down on the right and says "News & Events
(Click here for more)"

Can anyone help me identify which snippet of the CSS describes this section and/or the colour (incorrect shade of green) so that I can find it myself?

Many thanks!

Comment: Please post your code here and preferably a jsFiddle replicating your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colour for that link is on line `49` in `http://www.playlistforlife.org.uk/wp-content/themes/superior/user/user.css?ver=1.0.0`

I found this by right-clicking the link in Chrome, clicking `Inspect`, and then using the CSS panel, applied the `:hover` style to it. This then showed the CSS responsible for the hover colour.

Comment: Thanks Ruirize - That's great, but I can't find out how to edit user.css - in the editor there is only a file called "user-css.php"

Comment: Hi I managed to paste the code into custom.css which has fixed it - thanks :) p